# $current_user is empty in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, session, cookies, authentication, global

I'm trying to get the login data from outside of wordpress.

I mean, I have wordpress installed in `mysite/wp/` and I'm calling the following functions in `mysite/index.php`

```
include( 'wp/wp-load.php');  
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
print_r($current_user);
```

which prints an empty WP_User Object like this:

```
WP_User Object ( [data] => [ID] => 0 [caps] => Array ( ) [cap_key] => [roles] => Array ( ) [allcaps] => Array ( ) [filter] => )
```

Should I include something else? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks..

Comment: Works for me in my development setup. `var_dump` produces a nicely formatted display, unlike `print_r`. Or use `echo '<pre>'.print_r($current_user,true).'</pre>';`

Comment: Thanks. I solved my problem, and posting the answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem, and it could definitely help others too.

The problem was with my folder structure,
since it was like

- mysite.com
- mysite.com/mypage.php

  - mysite/wordpress/

the cookies were only valid for wordpress folder, and it's subdirectories.

In order to activate the cookies outside wordpress, I installed the [root Cookie](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/root-cookie) plugin, and everything works fine now.

### P.S.

Do **NOT** change the configuration of root Cookie. Just leave the Domain Name setting as empty.